# If $f:X \rightarrow Y$ sends constructible sets to constructible when $X,Y$ are affine varieties, the same holds if $X$ and $Y$ algebraic varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If a morphism $f:X \rightarrow Y$ of affine varieties $X$ and $Y$ sends constructible sets to constructible sets, show that the same statement holds when $X$ and $Y$ are assumed to be algebraic varieties.

My attempt:

Assuming that $f$ maps constructible sets to constructible sets when $X$ and $Y$ are affine, assume now that $X$ and $Y$ simply algebraic varieties. Since $X$ and $Y$ are algebraic varieties, they can be covered by a finite number of open affine varieties, say

$X=X_{1} \cup ... \cup X_{n}$

$Y=Y_{1} \cup ... \cup Y_{m}$

where each $X_{i}$ and $Y_{i}$ is affine. Let $C$ be a constructible subset of $X$. Since each $X_{i}$ is open it is constructible. Therefore $C \cap X_{i}$ is constructible for each $i$ since they are intersections of two constructible subsets. Therefore $C \cap X_{i}$ is constructible subset of $X$.

> This is where I get stuck. I'm not sure if I'm on the right track but I would like to show that $C \cap X_i$ is a constructible subset of $X_i$ and use the fact that it's a subset of an affine variety to conclude that its image is constructible. Taking the union of the images over i would show that $f(C)$ is a constructible subset of $Y$.

Comment: @D_S In my proof or in the statement of the problem?

Comment: @D_S The problem is definitely written as stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you need to be a little more careful- you don't mention the decomposition of $Y$ into affine varieties at all. If you successfully incorporate that, I think the paragraph you have in the block quote "this is where I get stuck" is a good idea and will successfully finish your proof.

Comment: I did mention that -- I said $Y$ is the union of the $Y_{i"}$'s which are affine varieties.

Comment: @TuoTuo But you didn't **use** the $Y_i$'s at all. Note, $f$ does *not* necessarily map each $X_i$ to a $Y_j$. What you have done is observe that the restriction $f |_{X_i} : X_i \to Y$, and $X_i \cap C$ is constructible; but $Y$ is not an affine variety.